# How to Get Location data from Photos in React Native Android 10

Tags: android, react-native, expo, android-10.0

MediaStore.Images.Media.LATITUDE and MediaStore.Images.Media.LONGITUDE was deprecated in Android Q.

Does anyway know how we can get the Media location on React Native with expo? Basically do the below without Ejecting.
[Android 10: fetch the gallery via MediaStore with location information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55186255/android-10-fetch-the-gallery-via-mediastore-with-location-information)

Thank you

```
import * as Permissions from 'expo-permissions';
import * as MediaLibrary from 'expo-media-library';
import Exif from 'react-native-exif'
...

    MediaLibrary.getAssetInfoAsync(asset).then(function (e) {
                                console.log("Location is ", e.location); //always null
                                if (e.location) {
                                    data.push(e);
                                }
                            });
    Exif.getLatLong(asset) //doesn't get location.
                          .then((loc) => { console.log('Location OK: ', loc) })
                          .catch(msg => console.log('messages: ' + msg))
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be an issue if you're using a real device and not an emulator.

When I use the iOS simulator, there are no issues getting the location with this method, if the image contains any location data.

```
const imageData = await MediaLibrary.getAssetInfoAsync(assetId);
console.log(imageData.location)
```

How ever, on my physical android device the locations field also resolves to `null`.
Even though the image i'm testing with is the same.

But when I use expo ImagePicker, location is shown if the image contains the informations.

Also, it may be unnecessary to use `react-native-exif`; the method `getAssetInfoAsync` already returns the image EXIF data.

Comment: Hey, for iOS it's working fine. Looking for an Android solution. Android, it doesn't work on a phone or simulator.